# How to set UILabel's line height?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, height, line

Was looking for answer in the google
Didn't find the solution on StackOverflow

[Posting modified solution of this post](https://www.belkadigital.com/articles/uilabel-line-height-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension

```
extension UILabel {
    func setLineHeight(lineHeight: CGFloat) {
        var attributeStringInitial: NSMutableAttributedString?
        var textInitial: String?
        
        if let text_ = self.text {
            attributeStringInitial = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text_)
            textInitial = text_
        } else if let text_ = self.attributedText {
            attributeStringInitial = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: text_)
            textInitial = text_.string
        }
        
        guard let attributeString = attributeStringInitial,
              let text = textInitial
        else { return }
        
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        
        style.lineSpacing = lineHeight
        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.count))
        self.attributedText = attributeString
    }
}
```